# Jupyter Kernel dying on macOS due to Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, ipython, macos-monterey

I am having trouble with a Jupyter script that I am using for a class at university. Useful information: I am using a MacBook Air (first time), macOS Monterey 12.0.1, M1 Apple chip, and I am working in a conda virtual environment with conda 4.11.0 and Python 3.9.7. This is the first part of the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras   <--
import tensorflow as tf   <--
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn import preprocessing
from keras import regularizers   <--
import random
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model   <--
import time
from IPython.display import Image
```

When I run it, I get this message: 
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

I tried commenting each row, and apparently, the problem is due to the ones that I highlighted with the arrow. So there is something wrong with TensorFlow. As suggested by my professor, I went on the terminal, typed ipython, then this:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ipython
```

I looked it up on the internet, and I understood that there are some incompatibilities between some Python packages and the M1 Apple chip. I tried to follow this https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos, but when I use the command written there, this is what happens

```
(phdcourse) alessandroruggieri@Alessandros-MacBook-Air ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/master/scripts/download_and_install.sh)"

ERROR: TensorFlow with ML Compute acceleration is only available on macOS 11.0 and later.
```

This is pretty weird, considering I have macOS 12.0.1 (as said at the beginning). 
To conclude, I have seen some posts about similar issues on the internet, but they all look rather confusing, so I would really appreciate an easy and clear help.

Comment: It seems, Tensorflow has not installed in your system correctly. Could you follow the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) to install tensorflow in your system and let us know if the issue still persists.